# Why do Atom, VSCode or Ava use more than one continuous integration services?

Tags: git, github, repository

Continuous integration services, like [Travis](http://travis-ci.org), [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) or [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) have been proofed to be really useful to make sure that the project is working as intended automatically.

**But why do some repositories use more than one CI?**

Doesn't one already do the job well? Is it to prevent a service or two not working as intended or down at some point?

For example:

[Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom) (3): CircleCI, Travis, AppVeyor
[VScode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) (2): Travis, AppVeyor
[Ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) (2): Travis, AppVeyor
[Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) (2): Travis, CircleCI

**Update:**

[React](https://github.com/facebook/react) made the switch from TravisCI to CircleCI long time ago.

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/8486

> For context, we're interested in moving over to CircleCI for now
>   because our Travis queue for the /facebook org on GitHub is
>   perpetually hours behind. On the other hand, Circle builds are able to
>   start almost instantaneously.

Is this related to why big projects use several CI services?

Comment: Why is this question on SuperUser?  this is a programming question.

Comment: @MarkArnott I don't think so. I didn't provide nor I expect code in the answer. What's more, Git, GitHub and repository can be used for both code and other non-programming stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can often do different jobs:

- Travis supports Linux and macOS, but currently not Windows.
- Circle CI seems to support macOS more reliably than Travis.
- AppVeyor supports *only* Windows, and it can do additional tasks – e.g. generate the "installer" packages for releases.